# Custom background resulting in custom button not showing

Tags: ios, uibutton, uibackgroundcolor

I set my custom background in my `AppDelegate.m`:

```
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"]]];
```

And in my viewcontroller i make my custom button before adding it as a subview:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.mainButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [self.mainButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.mainButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aButton"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.mainButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 100)];

    [self.view addSubview:self.mainButton];

}
```

Only my background is showing. If I remove the background - the button appears.

Comment: is it showing any log while running??

Comment: share your didFinishLaunchingWithOption method code here

Answer (score 0):

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aButton"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aButton"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 100)];

[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And do not forget the extention  "aButton.png" "aButton.jpg"...

Comment: I found my mistake. This was not it :) By the way, you don't need to add .png that is default.

Answer (score 0):

Set a pattern for UIViewController or just write a line

```
[self.View bringSubViewToFront:_button]
```